# Как задать ширину контейнера равную ширине родителя?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как задать ширину контейнера равную ширине родителя, не задавая ему явной ширины (px), чтобы родительский контейнер не растягивался по ширине при заполнении.

**ДОП**:

Родительский контейнер тоже не должен иметь фиксированную ширину, его ширина должна определяться вторым дочерним элементом.

```css
.mob-telephone {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* По этому элементу будет определяться ширина .mob-telephone */
.mob-telephone__number {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Этот элемент должен иметь ширину .mob-telephone и не должен иметь возможность влиять на неё, т.е не умещающийся текст должен переноситься на новую строчку самостоятельно без использования <br> 
*/
.mob-telephone__desc {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mob-telephone">
    <div class="mob-telephone__number">+7 (831) 123-23-23</div>
    <div class="mob-telephone__desc">Отдел производства металлоизделий</div>
</div>

<p style="font-style: italic;">Вот так дожно это выглядеть:</p>

<div class="mob-telephone">
    <div class="mob-telephone__number">+7 (831) 123-23-23</div>
    <div class="mob-telephone__desc">Отдел производства<br> металлоизделий</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.mob-telephone{
    display: inline-table
}
.mob-telephone__desc {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}
.mob-telephone__number {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div class="mob-telephone">
  <div class="mob-telephone__number">+7 (831) 123-23-23</div>
  <div class="mob-telephone__desc">Отдел производства металлоизделий</div>
</div>
```

Comment: в этом что-то есть, но хотелось бы увидеть вариант на div'ах

Comment: display: table-caption работает так как мне надо, но правильно ли его использовать без таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

```
родитель {
width = 500px; /* условно */
}
сынок {
width = 100%; 
}
```

сынок будет занимать 100% ширины родителя

Comment: Я наверно не ясно написал. Родительский контейнер тоже не должен иметь фиксированную ширину, его ширина должна определяться вторым дочерним элементом.

Comment: просто убрать стиль родителя:

Comment: оставь width = 100% сынку, тогда сынок не будет вылезать за пределы родителя, а родитель расширяться под размеры дочки.

Comment: Он и так не вылезает за пределы родителя. Пробовал. Просто также растягивает родителя.

Comment: тогда я тебя не понял

Comment: Окей, тогда так.
как мне сверстать код из "Вот так дожно это выглядеть" только без br и width

Comment: Если ты хочешь поместить только 2 слова, а чтоб третье переносилось, то `word-wrap:break-word` (при условии, что ширина div'a не вмещает больше этих 2х слов). Я бы на твоём месте задал равную ширину и номеру телефона, и названию отдела. Эти заморочки не стоят времени, которое ты на них тратишь. Или задал бы ширину контейнеру. В любом случаи без указания ширины в одном из предложенных вариантов ты не ограничишь место для текста, и тогда останется толькоко <br>.